# How do I get output of the cummulative Hazard ratio from coxph?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

How do I get output of the cummulative Hazard ratio from coxph?

I have my coxmodel

```
coxfit <- coxph(Surv(combi$survival, combi$realdeath) ~ combi$meanrr, combi)
```

and get the output

```
# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(combi$survival, realdeath) ~ combi$meanrr, 
#     data = combi)
# 
#                   coef exp(coef)  se(coef)     z       p
# combi$meanrr -0.004140  0.995869  0.000905 -4.57 4.8e-06
# 
# Likelihood ratio test=21.9  on 1 df, p=2.94e-06
# n= 311, number of events= 70
```

I know I can calculate the Hazard Ratio manually with `hr = exp(-0.004140)` and the `ci= exp(-0.004140-1.96*0.000905)`,`exp(-0.004140+1.96*0.000905)`

This will give me the HR of an increase of one unit with confidence interval.

Is there a function which will give me the results as a vector or data.frame? Preferentially if I could define the number of units of interest, like

`somefunction(coxfit, unit_step)`

but just calculating the cumulative hazard ration is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

summary(coxfit) gives the correct answer

```
coxph(formula = Surv(combi$survival, realdeath) ~ meanrr, data = combi)

  n= 311, number of events= 70 

             coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
meanrr -0.0041399  0.9958687  0.0009055 -4.572 4.83e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

       exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
meanrr    0.9959      1.004    0.9941    0.9976

Concordance= 0.661  (se = 0.035 )
Rsquare= 0.068   (max possible= 0.92 )
Likelihood ratio test= 21.86  on 1 df,   p=2.938e-06
Wald test            = 20.9  on 1 df,   p=4.83e-06
Score (logrank) test = 21.24  on 1 df,   p=4.051e-06
```

where the hazard ratio for one units increased is given as exp(coef) and the confidence interval as lower/upper .95

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your question fully. How does `summary()' gives the results you were asking for; 1) *cumulative* hazard, 2) as a vector, or for that matter anymore (relevant) information than you posted in the question?
Feel free to clarify - we are all learning.....

Comment: The hazard ratio is the ratio of two hazard functions with different values of the dependent parameter. In practise we are only interested in the total follow up time tmax the cumulative value. Dince coxph calculates the coefficient c(i) for the dependent variable i, the hazard ratio for a one unit step of i is simply exp(i). By sonme reason coxph does not directly give that parameter, but summary(coxphfit) does. Since it is the cumulative value for the whole follow up period it is a scalar

Comment: I am under the impression that Cumulative Hazard is usually defined as ...

\Lambda(t) = \int_0^T \lamdba(t) dt.

That is, an accumulation of hazard \lambda(t) over time, noting upper case and lower case lambdas in that equation.

Comment: Yes but I am talking about the cumulative hazard ratio.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract cumulative hazard using `basehaz()` or `survfit()`.

Typing `str(basehaz(coxfit))` or `str(survfit(coxfit))` in your case for your model will reveal the structure of the data object, and provides the clue that `basehaz(coxfit)$hazard` or `survfit(coxfit)$cumhaz` yields a vector/dataframe-friendly output you were after.

The help notes at `?basehaz` will tell you that `survfit()` is the preferred approach, and indeed the latter provides a comprehensive output, including CIs.

Comment: I'm not sure what the output from either two means. At least it is not directly the cummulative hazard ratio. However I found a solution given below